# Can Akamai create different resolutions of uploaded video stream

Tags: video, youtube, resolution, akamai

We are using Akamai Media Server API to upload our videos to its CDN. My concern is how I can provide different video resolutions / bitrates as youtube provide.
e.g. Video upload in 1080 HD, youtube automatically converts 720, 480, 360, 240, 144 pixel formats.
Same I want with Akamai.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use intermediate service to convert and encode your HD video in multi-bitrate. You can have an on premise encoder or use third party services like [zencoder.com](http://zencoder.com) or [encoding.com](http://encoding.com) to convert the uploaded video.